# Osgeo4w Libraries downlaod

Tags: qgis-3, osgeo4w

I recently tried to update my QGIS version with the installation of Osgeo4w libraries. I was told that the installation was supposed to take something like 20 gb space on my computer.

While downloading the libraries and not even crossing the half way line, a 20 gb library space has already been downloaded, and it didn't even showed sign of finishing.

I tried to find the location of the libraries on my computer, but I couldn't find it. The path was supposed to be a temporary folder called "C:\Users\CARMEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp", but it just didn't exist.

Any body know where I can find those libraries? Is there a new path where it goes as default after finishing its download?

Comment: did you look at C:\OSGeo4W64  and its subdirectories?

Comment: That is a temporary folder and it is deleted when the installation is finished. You must have selected the installation path, something like C: \ OSGeo4W64. There is everything you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Fran.
Although I looked deeply into my C drive folder, I'll take a look again according to what you and @Kurt suggested